# Sklearn KernelDensity gives identical results for two different models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I'm having trouble with KernelDensity from sklearn. I put in two completely different arrays to create two different models, but the two models have identical results (scores). They should have different results for different models, shouldn't they?

Here's my code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
import numpy as np
kde = KernelDensity(kernel="gaussian", bandwidth=15)
def reproducible_example():
     X1 = np.array([9,18,28,35,54,59,65,83,89,116,119,124,144])
     X2 = np.array([39,51,57,61,66,81,88,103,120,126,130,132,134])
     model1 = kde.fit(X1[:, np.newaxis])
     model2 = kde.fit(X2[:, np.newaxis])
     X_plot = np.linspace(0, 129, 130)
     score1 = model1.score_samples(X_plot[:, np.newaxis])
     score2 = model2.score_samples(X_plot[:, np.newaxis])
     print(np.exp(score1) == np.exp(score2))
reproducible_example()
```

The expected output is `False`, as the two different models should return two different scores. Instead, the output is this:

```
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
```

Indicating that the two results are identical. How is that possible?

Comment: `model1` and `model2` point to the same `kde`.  Create a unique `kde` for each and see what you get.

Comment: @rickhg12hs then what's the point of storing it a model?

Comment: I don't think it's getting "stored".  I think it's more like pointers.

Comment: @rickhg12hs it is successful but I still don't get what purpose it could have to return a pointer instead of a unique object

Comment: `model1 = kde... ` means "make `model1` point to `kde`".  `model2 = kde... ` means  "make `model2` point to `kde` too". See [A Word About Names and Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects).